# Notice on admin after upgrading from 2.9.0 to 2.10.2

Tags: ee2-upgrades

I upgraded the expression engine from version from 2.9.0 to 2.10.2.It started showing the notice in the admin:

> Your ExpressionEngine installation’s version (2.9.2) is not consistent
>   with the reported version (2.10.1). Please update your installation of
>   ExpressionEngine again.

What does this mean? Need help.
PS: I am new to ee

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correct it is because $config['app_version'] in config.php still has the old version number.

Comment: Yes it was same issue. I have to do it again because I found it was caused due to internet connection issue.